# Beatport new interface

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe, navigation

Beatports new interface has solved a major problem I was looking for the solution too.

Namely, it keeps a "player" interface at the moment and you can browser to different parts of the site (also changing the url) without reloading or interrupting the player.

I cannot for the life of me understand how they have done this, can any of you guys figure it out?!

Many thanks for any replies I get

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are just using AJAX to load new content but have taken care to make it work and look pretty seamless. You can get better insight into what events are attached to what elements via the [Visual Events](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) bookmarklet. Once you find the code that triggers the event, you can run the obfuscated javascript through [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to examine it more closely.

Specifically, it looks like they're adding click handlers to all anchor tags, passing off the event if it was triggered with a middle click or modified with a keyboard key, otherwise passing it to a dynamic loader which handles state and other specific conditions like multiple clicks. The seamlessness of it comes from the way they deal with URLs making every page bookmarkable and the browser history so the back and forward buttons work as you would expect on a "normal" site.

Comment: I want to just reload my extension on every new page load but attaching my event handler to anchor tags means that my script gets called X times (where X = number of handlers :S)